# 503 error when trying to fetch data from my backend

Tags: asp.net-core, frontend, nuxt.js

I have a aspnet backend running but when I try to fetch data from what I have of the frontend(done in nuxt) the frontend breaks and returns a 503.

```html
<script>
//code
const {res}  = await useFetch(()=>'http://localhost:5225/api/res/get/2')
//code
</script>
```

Swagger works fine on the backend if that matters here.
I also tried curling my backend to see if I could get anything useful - it indicated a redirect to port 7225 and curling that port I get empty replies(This is after I tried deleting applicanthost.config as suggested in some other threads and rebuilt the project).

[image: curl port 5225]

[image: Curl port 7225]

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

UPDATE

Yall were right about there being a typo somewhere and I got a response by curling localhost:7225. However I still don't have luck on the frontend after correcting the url but I don't get a 503 anymore-instead its unresponsive and sometimes nothing shows up on the page. I've additionally tried:

```
'''
async fetch(){
    this.stay = await 
this.$axios.$get('https://localhost:7225/Res/get/2');
}
'''
```

To no avail. I've also tried fetching from a clean nuxt3 app with the same results.

Can yall tell me a good direction to go from here?

Comment: If you have nothing with your second curl, the issue is on the backend (not Nuxt's side).

Comment: In the first request, the Backend is redirecting you to https://localhost:7225/. This happens because you have the HttpsRedirectionMiddleware configured (`.UseHttpsRedirection()`). In the second request, you are not getting anything back from the server because your URL isn't correct. You're requesting using HTTP through a port that only accepts HTTPS connections.

Comment: 503 error means server un-avaliable. But according to your image, I don't see the server return the 503 error. Please check your url to make sure you use the right http or https with the url and test again.